# Answering my own question

Tags: discussion

Is it correct to answer my own question to share the information I knew about a place. Though [Stack Overflow states this as correct](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), my [questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/accomodation-facilities-in-valparai) have been blocked since I asked and answered them immediately. Why is it so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

answering your own question is perfectly valid, that's what the

[image]

is for. This has always been allowed on all SE sites, and was [reinforced in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132887/217110)

> Since Stack Overflow began, spontaneously sharing what you've learned
> by posting a question and immediately answering it has been allowed
> and even encouraged:
>
> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a **relevant Stack    Exchange site**.

Providing the question and answer is [**on topic**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there is nothing to stop you doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Asking a question, then going off to investigate, and finding a solution later which you then share is fine

Asking a made up question just to give a specific answer isn't generally approved of, but can be OK in certain situations

Asking a made up question to give a promotional answer is never allowed

(Thinking of a question when you're off-line, finding the answer later, then asking + answering here is normally fine, but make sure you really are sharing something useful from it, not just showing off or promoting something)

Remember - the site is about solving problems. Answers that don't solve real problems aren't right here. If you just want to share some general information about travel, try Wiki Voyage or your own blog!

Comment: There is mostly a doubt on the made up question. I would say it depends whether someone would ask the question. And obviously it should meet all the requirements of a question.

Comment: Based on the other answers kols has given, it's safe to assume he isn't a spammer.

Comment: I got it. I'll post questions regarding problems and solutions only. Thakyou for the information.

Comment: It's great now I got all my questions removed.(even the previous ones). Why?

Comment: Why is Travel an exception to the [general SE rules on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz/132887#132887)? Providing the question is [on topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) why can't a user simply make up a question they think might be useful and post an answer?

Comment: @Liam We follow the same rules laid out in that post. It all needs to start with a problem, which you either need solving, or you've already solved. If you just want to share some general info without there ever being a problem, SE isn't the right locate for that

Comment: Asking a question when you already know the answer is fine too. If you did the research before you got around to asking here, that's no objection against asking and self-answering. There's even a user interface feature to post a question and answer at the same time.

Comment: @Gilles It still needs to start with a question though! Starting with the answer is the problematic thing